# How to read input when debugging GO in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to debug a Go program in Visual Studio Code 1.24.0 which goes like this:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
 fmt.Println("Hello World")
 var input int
 fmt.Scanf("%d", &input)
 fmt.Printf("Hello %v", input)
}
```

When start debugging, the program waits for input. I tried giving input via Debug Console, but it didn't work. Properties like externalConsole don't seem to work in launch.json for Go. Any inputs?

Answer (score 46):

There's a simple solution now. You can append the following line to your launch configuration:

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

See [vscode-go](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go) issue [#2015](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2015#issuecomment-1015479431)

Comment: Voted for this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'm happy to share that a more usable solution (It automatically runs the task before launching) is found.

...

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Connect to server",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "preLaunchTask": "delve",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 23456,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And
tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "delve",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "dlv debug --headless --listen=:23456 --api-version=2 \"${workspaceFolder}\"",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "clear": false
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": ""
                },
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                    "beginsPattern": {
                        "regexp": ".*"
                    },
                    "endsPattern": {
                        "regexp": ".*server listening.*"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It expects you are working with a go.mod since delve also looks for it to debug the directory.

Comment: It failed saying `open *\__debugèbin: The process can't access this file because another process already uses it`
:(

Comment: that happened to me when another session was debugging, just make sure nothing else is debugging, or in the worst scenario you could go and kill all processes running "dlv".

Comment: `"command": "dlv debug --headless --listen=:23456 --api-version=2 "` worked for me while the original solution gave `cannot import absolute path` error. I'm on Linux.

Comment: Interesting. I actually develop on Linux with it. But it is great it worked with your adjustment. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: works like a charm. tested under Linux.

Answer (score 4):

In the same Issue HowieLiuX shared a sinmpler solution that works for me:

In tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd ${fileDirname} && dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I, however, had to change command to:

```
"command": "dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2",
```

since I'm running through powershell.

Then in launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Connect to server",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

First run the task then debug.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that update on the issue I reported in my own answer. I have updated it accordingly.

Comment: This works, we just need to make sure we manually run the task before launching code ... run the task with Ctrl + Shift + B, (it might fail to launch it since that same shortcut sometimes works for setting debug breakpoints, if that is the case adjust your shortcuts or run it from vscode menus: Terminal > Run task > "echo" > Continue without scanning ...)

Comment: It failed saying `open *\__debugèbin: The process can't access this file because another process already uses it`
:(

Comment: Change of command you did makes it work on my Linux machine.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [vscode-go issue 219](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/219)

The workaround (proposed by [`KingRikkie`](https://github.com/KingRikkie)) is:

> There is a workaround however. I wrote a script that does the following:

- Compile your app without optimizations and inlining
- Start app in a new window
- Attach delve headlessly onto its process id.

> I then created a new task in VScode that starts the script and specified said task under `preLaunchTask` in a remote debug configuration in `launch.json`.
>
> In my case a powershell script resting inside `{workspaceRoot}` compiling a package called '`main`' in '`main`' dir:
>
> ```
> $EXECUTABLE_NAME="main"
> $EXECUTABLE_PATH=".\main"
> $GoPath=((go env | Select-String -Pattern "GOPATH=" | Out-String) -split "=")[1].TrimEnd()
> $GoPath+="\bin"
> Set-Location $EXECUTABLE_PATH
> Start-Process go -ArgumentList 'build -gcflags "-N -l"' -Wait -NoNewWindow # compile without optimizations and inlining
> Start-Process ".\$EXECUTABLE_NAME.exe"
> $timeOut = 20
> $started = $false
> # wait for process to start
> Do {
>     Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
>     $timeOut--
>     $Proc = Get-Process main -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
>     If ($Proc) { 
>         $started = $true 
>     }
> }
> Until ($started -or $timeOut -eq 0)
> If (!($started)) {
>     Write-Error 'Process did not start' 
>     Exit
> }
> $ProcId=($Proc | Select-Object -expand Id)
> Start-Process -FilePath "$GoPath\dlv.exe" -ArgumentList "attach $ProcId --headless --listen=:2345 --log" -WindowStyle Hidden
> ```
>
> The task:
>
> ```
> "label": "debug-attach",
> "type": "shell",
> "command": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File ${workspaceRoot}\\debug-attach.ps1",
> "presentation": {
>     "reveal": "silent",
>     "panel": "shared",
>     "echo": false
> }
> ```
>
> The launch configuration:
>
> ```
> "name": "Attach",
> "type": "go",
> "request": "launch",
> "mode": "remote",
> "remotePath": "${workspaceRoot}\\main",
> "port": 2345,
> "host": "127.0.0.1",
> "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\main",
> "preLaunchTask": "debug-attach",
> "env": {},
> "args": [],
> "showLog": true
> ```
>
> When I hit F5 now my app will pop up and debugging will automatically start, delve is hidden.

---

Since July 2018, [HowieLiuX](https://github.com/HowieLiuX) reported the [following workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/219#issuecomment-449621513) in Dec. 2018

> using remote debug + vscode task:
>
> ```
> task.json
>
> {
>     // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
>     // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
>     "version": "2.0.0",
>     "tasks": [
>         {
>             "label": "echo",
>             "type": "shell",
>             "command": "cd ${fileDirname} && dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2",
>             "problemMatcher": [],
>             "group": {
>                 "kind": "build",
>                 "isDefault": true
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

And:

> ```
> launch.json:
>
> {
>     // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
>     // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
>     // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
>     "version": "0.2.0",
>     "configurations": [
>         {
>             "name": "Connect to server",
>             "type": "go",
>             "request": "launch",
>             "mode": "remote",
>             "remotePath": "${fileDirname}",
>             "port": 2345,
>             "host": "127.0.0.1",
>             "program": "${fileDirname}",
>             "env": {},
>             "args": []
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> Run the task using shortcut key (shift + cmd + B in Mac OS): VSCode will start a new shell and run the delve server.
>   Pressing F5 to debug the `.go` file.

Answer (score 2):

Setting console

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

did not work when I have

```
"program": "${fileDirname}",
```

defined by vscode as default.

It changes directory to /.vscode directory.

Setting "console", and changing "program" to "${workspaceFolder}" worked for me.
launch.json looks like this:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Launch Package",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "auto",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
  }
]
```